# Neo4j : Loading to memory in batches

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a large transaction node (3 million rows) and very little memory (8GB of RAM). I have already created the transaction node using Periodic Commit and now I want to create relationship between account node and transaction node.

This is what I am using :

```
MATCH (tx:Transaction),(a:Account)
WHERE tx.tx_id = a.tx_id
CREATE (a)-[:HAS_TRANS]->(tx)
```

However, it runs out of memory because it first loads the entire transaction data into memory before creating relationship.

Ideally, I want to load just a 10000 records in memory, create relationship, clean the memory and then create relationship for the next 10000 records.

I am aware that we can create the relationship while creating the transaction table on periodic commit. However, I am curious if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your query to look for the first 10k transactions that do not have a `HAS_TRANS` relationship from an `Account` labeled node.

```
MATCH (tx:Transaction)
WHERE NOT (:Account)-[:HAS_TRANS]->(tx)
WITH tx
LIMIT 10000
MATCH (a:Account)
WHERE tx.tx_id = a.tx_id
CREATE (a)-[:HAS_TRANS]->(tx)
```

Make sure you have indexes on Transaction(tx_id) and Account(tx_id).

Probably the best way to iterate over the batches in cypher until you are done is to use `apoc.periodic.iterate`.

You can experiment with something like this.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (tx:Transaction)
   WHERE NOT (:Account)-[:HAS_TRANS]->(tx)
   WITH tx
   MATCH (a:Account)
   WHERE tx.tx_id = a.tx_id
   RETURN tx, a",
  "CREATE (a)-[:HAS_TRANS]->(tx)",
  {batchSize:10000, parallel:true}
)
```

The other approach would be to write a little script and call the cypher multiple times.

Comment: Thank you Dave. That worked! My follow up question is : How do we put this in a loop to create relationships for all the 3 million records?